# How to convert string to date in oracle using sql?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a oracle database table `(product, productionDate)`. The data type of `productionDate` is String yymmdd (example: 131006). I want to retrieve information using "order by productionDate". If that column is Date type, I can query easily. But as the data type is string, I could not retrieve the desired query. 
Do i need to write any procedure or function to retrieve this? Or by using only sql I can do this?

Answer (score 4):

This may be relevant for you:

https://forums.oracle.com/thread/600694

```
TO_DATE(date_col, 'YYMMDD')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use format `YYMMDD` then again you can use ordering by `productionDate`.

Records from year `12` will always follow records from year `11`, same for months and dates.

Just be sure to create index for that column.